# How can i switch between Intel and Nvidia Graphics card?

Tags: graphics, nvidia, intel

I have an Intel i5 processor with a HD IGP and a Nvidia 950M, but all applications use the Intel HD. How can I switch graphics when I run a game?

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't want all graphics (not just games) through the nvidia card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to install the official nvidia drivers:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Then, after rebooting, you can choose the card to use in the programm "NVIDIA X Server Settings" in the option "PRIME-Profiles"

Note that you can't use both at the same time. You either have to render everything using Nvidia, or everything using Intel.

Comment: thx. after reboot is ok