# Laptop not turning off

Tags: system-installation, release-hera

As the title says, when trying to turn off my laptop with eOS 5.1 running, it just freezes and turns off only after the battery is completely worn-out (laptop was very hot when this happened, don't know what it was doing).

This happened when I had it installed but also on a live-usb, or even when trying to install the OS: For example at the end of the installation process, when it asks to reboot the system in order to use the new OS, it just freezes instead of rebooting normally.

I'm (trying) to run eOS on an Asus ZenBook Pro UX580GE-BN085R.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Also, when trying to install eOS the touchpad worked only 1 out of 10 times, I'd appreciate if you could help with this as well.

Answer (score 1):

This exact behaviour happens to me as well if the nVidia drivers are not installed. In terminal, run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. Reboot when it's done (or force shut-down).

After reboot, use the nVidia Settings app from the Application menu to switch between the integrated Intel GPU and the dedicated nVidia one.

For more information look here:
[How can i switch between Intel and Nvidia Graphics card?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7967/how-can-i-switch-between-intel-and-nvidia-graphics-card),